# How to find Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes, algorithmically?

Tags: equivalence-relations, formal-languages, regular-language

Say I have a regular expression given, or a language given in set form.

Examples:

$$ L= \{ w \in \{a,b\}^* |  w \ \text{ matches} \ \  a^*b^*(bab)^*\} \\
L = \{ w | count_a(w) = 5 \} \\
L= \{ w \in \{a,b\}^* | aab \ \   \text{is substring of w\}} $$

Is there an algorithmic-like approach to finding the equivalence classes or do I have to try out different strings and test them with respect to the Nerode relation ?

---

Now my question:

How do I quickly find the equivalence classes for a given language ?

Whats the trick/intuition ?

Answer (score 1):

For each word $u$, let
$$
 u^{-1}L = \{v\in A^*\mid uv \in L\}
$$
These languages can be computed recursively by using the following formulas, where $u, v \in A^*$ and $a \in A$:
\begin{align*}
(uv)^{-1}L &= v^{-1}(u^{-1}L) \\
u^{-1}(L_1 \cup L_2)       &= u^{-1}L_1 \cup u^{-1}L_2\\
u^{-1}(L_1 \setminus  L_2) &= u^{-1}L_1 \setminus  u^{-1}L_2\\
u^{-1}(L_1 \cap L_2)       &= u^{-1}L_1 \cap u^{-1}L_2\\
a^{-1}(L_1L_2)             &=
\begin{cases}
  (a^{-1}L_1)L_2                 &\text{if $1 \notin L_1$,}\\
    (a^{-1}L_1)L_2 + a^{-1}L_2  &\text{if $1 \in L_1$}\\
\end{cases}\\
a^{-1}L^*       &= (a^{-1}L)L^*
\end{align*}
For instance, let $A = \{a, b\}$ and $L = A^*aabA^*$.  Then
\begin{align*}
 1^{-1}L &= L \\
    a^{-1}L &= A^*aabA^* \cup abA^* = L_1 \\ 
    b^{-1}L &= L \\
 a^{-1}L_1 &= a^{-1}(A^*aabA^*) \cup a^{-1}(abA^*) = A^*aabA^* \cup abA^* \cup bA^* = L_2 \\
 b^{-1}L_1 &= b^{-1}(A^*aabA^*) \cup b^{-1}(abA^*) = A^*aabA^* = L \\
a^{-1}L_2 &= a^{-1}(A^*aabA^*) \cup a^{-1}(abA^*) \cup a^{-1}(bA^*) =  A^*aabA^* \cup abA^* \cup bA^* = L_2 \\
b^{-1}L_2 &= b^{-1}(A^*aabA^*) \cup b^{-1}(abA^*) \cup b^{-1}(bA^*) = L \cup A^* = A^*  \\
a^{-1}L_3 &= a^{-1}A^* = A^*\\
b^{-1}L_3 &= b^{-1}A^* = A^*
\end{align*}
Therefore, there are four Nerode classes, associated to the words $1$, $a$, $aa$ and $aab$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the DFA minimization algorithm? This is probably the easiest way to compute the Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes.

Given a regular expression, it should be straight-forward to construct a DFA.